# How do I get a prolog rule that, when it fails, returns to the beginning of the rule?

Tags: cryptography, prolog, logic, gnu

I'm getting a headache staring at this prolog code and I can't seem to wrap my head around what has to be done...

Basically, the code is trying to break a given protocol, meaning there's some secret data that the attacker wants to gain knowledge of.
So the attacker tries to attack to gain this secret. To do this, he must have a successful run of the protocol.

```
successfulRun(Init_1,Init_2,Init_3,RespGet_1,RespGet_2,RespGet_3,Resp_1,Resp_2,Resp_3,XchdGet_1)
```

Init, Resp and Xchd are the names of the messages sent.
This predicate basically says that a successful run is when some Init_X (X are message parts) is sent, the receiver of Init_X sent RespGet_X as a response, the attacker intercepted RespGet_X and sent Resp_X himself, and the receiver of Resp_X sent XchdGet_X as a response.

Then I have a full run, which I take note of.

```
asserta(fullRun(Init_1,Init_2,Init_3,RespGet_1,RespGet_2,RespGet_3,Resp_1,Resp_2,Resp_3,XchdGet_1))
```

The secret leaks if the attacker knows the secret after the successful run.
If the secret doesn't leak, the knowledge gained during the attack has to be deleted (because in reality you shouldn't be able to attack one instance of an interaction twice).
Then a new attack try is started.

If an attack succeeds and the secret is leaked, a little info on how the attacker got the secret is written.

```
tryToAttack(Secret) :-
  successfulRun(Init_1,Init_2,Init_3,RespGet_1,RespGet_2,RespGet_3,Resp_1,Resp_2,Resp_3,XchdGet_1),
  asserta(fullRun(Init_1,Init_2,Init_3,RespGet_1,RespGet_2,RespGet_3,Resp_1,Resp_2,Resp_3,XchdGet_1)),
  (
    (
      leaks(Secret),!
    );
    (
      \+leaks(secret),
      (
        deleteAttackKnowledge;
        (
          tryToAttack(Secret),
          true
        )
      )
    )
  ),
  writeAttackPattern(Secret,Init_1,Init_2,Init_3,RespGet_1,RespGet_2,RespGet_3,Resp_1,Resp_2,Resp_3,XchdGet_1).
```

Okay, here's where the problem starts:
During a successful run, attack knowledge is extracted. This knowledge is asserted as a fact! If it weren't persistent, there would be no problem. So an alternative could be to not make the attack knowledge persistent.

If the run is successful, but we already had a full run like it, I want to do another run from the beginning that is not the same as the last run. I also want all attack knowledge gained during the last run deleted.

The problem I see is: If I put the

```
(
  fullRun(...),
  deleteAttackKnowledge
)
```

at the end of successfulRun, Prolog tries to go back to init or resp, where the attacker builds his messages. If Prolog goes back to resp, the new run does not get the attack knowledge from respGet.

I want to
1. do a run
2. see if this run had already been done
3. If it has been done already, delete all attack knowledge and go to (1), doing a different run.

```
successfulRun(Init_1,Init_2,Init_3,RespGet_1,RespGet_2,RespGet_3,Resp_1,Resp_2,Resp_3,XchdGet_1) :-
  init(Init_1,Init_2,Init_3),
  canBuild(Init_1),
  canBuild(Init_2),
  canBuild(Init_3),
  respGet(RespGet_1,RespGet_2,RespGet_3,Init_1,Init_2,Init_3),
  extractAttackKnowledge(RespGet_1),
  extractAttackKnowledge(RespGet_2),
  extractAttackKnowledge(RespGet_3),
  resp(Resp_1,Resp_2,Resp_3),
  canBuild(Resp_1),
  canBuild(Resp_2),
  canBuild(Resp_3),
  xchdGet(XchdGet_1,Resp_1,Resp_2,Resp_3),
  extractAttackKnowledge(XchdGet_1).
```

Notes for successfulRun:
init,resp : what the attacker sends
respGet,XchdGet : what the other party sends after a message from the attacker
canBuild : can the attacker build the message part from his knowledge (beginning knowledge + attack knowledge)?
extractAttackKnowledge : extracts new attack knowledge from the message parts

Thanks in advance,
Daniel W.

P.S.: Please feel free to comment if anything is unclear.

Comment: Is it necessary to globally declare the gained information this way? Would it be too much more complicated to pass this information around in variables?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To get rid of the learned information from a failed attempt, you can use the retractall/1 predicate.

For example:

```
deleteAttackKnowledge :- retractall(fullRun(_,_,_,_,_,_,_,_,_,_)).
```

Note: If you declare fullRun/10 to be dynamic (by adding the line ":- dynamic(fullRun/10)." to the top of your code), it will be easier for the interpreter to handle.

As I do not completely understand what you are doing so far, I'm going to leave my answer at this for the moment, and if I figure something out that could help, I'll come back and either add another answer or send you a message about it.

Comment: I solved this problem by storing the information in variables instead of asserting them. Thank you for your help, this would have solved the problem, too.